# Get process status by pid in Ruby

Tags: ruby, process-management

Is there a way to get a process's child process status based on its PID in Ruby?

For example, in Python you can do psutil.Process(pid).status

Comment: I believe the Process Module has what you need in it:  http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Process.html

Comment: What OS(es) do you need this to work on?

Comment: @vlasits Process module doesn't have any method to get state of running process, only exited processes.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a portable ruby method to get process state of a running process.  You can do `Process.wait` and check `$?.exitstatus`, but that doesn't look like what you want.  For a posix solution, you could use

```
`ps -o state -p #{pid}`.chomp
```

to get the letter code ps produces for process state

```
PROCESS STATE CODES
Here are the different values that the s, stat and state output specifiers
(header "STAT" or "S") will display to describe the state of a process.
D    Uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
R    Running or runnable (on run queue)
S    Interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
T    Stopped, either by a job control signal or because it is being traced.
W    paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
X    dead (should never be seen)
Z    Defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent.
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but shouldn't the `-o=state=` be `-o state`? Doing it with the equals signs doesn't work on my linux box.

Comment: @BenCrowell I don't know why I wrote that 10 years ago.  The equals can be used to rename the column headers, but it's irrelevant here.  Edited the original to be correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing. It's a shame ProcessStatus doesn't seem to be able to get initialized from a live pid. This is vital stuff if you want to do anything like a safe timed kill of a child process.

In any case,
it's the second line in `/proc/$pid/status` if you're on Linux.:
`status_line = File.open("/proc/#{pid}/status") {|f| f.gets; f.gets }`

Most likely much much faster than anything involving an external program.

Comment: Simple and elegant solution to avoid relying on external programs (and shelling out), thank you.

Answer (score 0):

On OS X, I setup a string:

```
outputstring="ps -O=S -p #{mypid}"
```

then execute it in a %x call:

```
termoutput=%x[#{outputstring}]
```

I can display that if needed, or just keep the output clean and act on the State I found with the call.